# Unable to access wordpress plugin settings

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

I installed the plugin but I am unable to edit the settings of the plugin, I activate it. But the plugin is not showing on the menu bar and if I try to access the setting from the installed plugins page, the setting is still not showing. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Which plugin is it? first you should check if the plugin is compatible with the version of WordPress and the theme you are using.

in any case the reasons can be numerous.

Sometimes it happens that it is a server setting problem, especially the memory limit. Other times it can be a user permissions issue.